# How to delete all Command Bars in Excel 2007 template .xltx and add own command bar with own controls?

Tags: c#, custom-controls, vsto, excel-2007, excel-template

I use VS 2010 for creating Excel 2007 xltx template. I want to remove all Excel command bars and disable to show them users and add own command bar with my controls. And in some controls I want to call VBA function that will be in this template. I think this operation I must do in :

```
private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ThisWorkbook_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.
I use VS 2010 for creating Excel 2007 xltx template. I want to remove all Excel command bars and disable to show them users and add own command bar with my controls. And in some controls I want to call VBA function that will be in this template. I think this operation I must do in :

```
private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ThisWorkbook_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

**UPD1:**
I try :

```
private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (CommandBar bar in this.Application.ThisWorkbook.CommandBars)
            {
                bar.Visible = false;
                //or  bar.Delete();
            }            
        }
```

But I get error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application.get_ThisWorkbook()
   at T100.ThisWorkbook.ThisWorkbook_Startup(Object sender, EventArgs e) in G:\PROJECTS\T100\T100\ThisWorkbook.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookImpl.OnStartup()
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookImpl.WorkbookExtensionImpl.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.OnStartup()
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookBase.OnStartup()
   at T100.ThisWorkbook.FinishInitialization() in G:\PROJECTS\T100\T100\ThisWorkbook.Designer.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookBase.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.FinishInitialization()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.ExecutePhase(ExecutionPhases executionPhases)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IExecuteCustomization2.ExecuteEntryPoints()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new ribbon to your project and set this in your ribbon xml

```
<ribbon startFromScratch="true">
```

If you use the ribbon designer you can find startFromScratch property in your properties window set this to "true".

Comment: Yes its sets in Ribbon Visual Designer